# Скрипт простого онлайн чата

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт простого онлайн чата, такой простой чтоб я смог разобраться!
В нете полно скриптов но они все сложные и сделаны на jquery или jabber ни стем ни другим у меня желания связываться не возникло.

Comment: http://august4u.biz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А тебе что нужно? большинство простые, вот к примеру: [Создаем Ajax-чат с использованием PHP, Javascript (jQuery) и MySQL](http://i-wanna-think.ru/sozdaem-ajax-chat-s-ispolzovaniem-php-javascript-jquery-i-mysql/)

Comment: Да именно такого плана простое но вашь пример на  jquery((((

Comment: @Kirpich643, а что плохого в этой библиотеке? Вы готовы написать без jQuery?

Comment: ну собственно я написал, так что список сообщений обновляется ajax запросом по таймеру - этот способ слишком сильно грузит сервер да и сообщения приходят не совсем мгновенно, нужно что-то другое на, я думаю в сторону SSE но тогда у меня возникла куча проблем с сервером на php, вообщем нужно вытягивать ответ непосредственно из mysql но я не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: используй GAE

Answer (score 3):

> такой простой чтоб я смог разобраться!

Проще некуда, 5 минут

```
<iframe id="chatFrame" name="chatFrame" src="chatFrame.php"></iframe>

<form action="chatFrame.php" target="chatFrame" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function chatFrame(frameId)
{
    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        document.getElementById(frameId).src = document.getElementById(frameId).src;
    }, 2000);
}

chatFrame('chatFrame');
//Еще прикрутить функцию для submit
</script>

chatFrame.php
<?php

//Запросы к бд сами
echo 'Мы сообщения чата<br />';

if(isset($_POST['message']))
{
    echo $_POST['message'];
}

?>
```

и готово)